# Create an msi package which installs both 32-bit and 64-bit resources on a machine

Tags: wix, windows-installer, 32bit-64bit, firebreath

I need to create an MSI package which installs both 32-bit and 64-bit .dll files of a firebreath  based plugin on a machine.

What I want to achieve is have both resources installed and use the one suitable depending on the Browser (32-bit or 64-bit). For instance, if I have a 64-bit machine with Windows, Chrome 64-bit and Firefox 32-bit; I want to be able to use my plugin from both browsers.

To do so, I am using Visual Studio 2008 and Wix. 
Up to now I was able to create a 32-bit .dll which is converted in a 32-bit .msi and a 64-bit .dll which fails to be converted to a 64-bit .msi, due to a heat.exe bug. I get something similar to this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firebreath-dev/HmGYEgZamUQ/35WJWfB4zegJ

The implementation mentioned before would create 2 different .msi installers (if the 64-bit msi didn't fail). What I would like to do is generate both .dll files (32-bit .dll and 64-bit .dll) and then package them in one single .msi installer which registers both.

Is this possible and if so what would be the best way to do it?

Comment: Christopher is right, the cleanest method is to create two MSI packages wrapped by a bootstrapper. Most setup authoring tools can help you do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Windows Installer doesn't support this.  Strictly speaking an .MSI package is platform specific.  There are some hacks and tricks to create a "hybrid" installer.  This entails creating a 32bit MSI that subverts MSI checks to install files to 64 bit locations and custom actions to create 64bit registry keys.

The book answer is to create a 32bit and 64bit MSI and then encapsulate them in a bootstrapper that registeres itself with Programs and Features and installs the 2 MSI's under the covers.  In WiX this would be accomplished using Burn to chain the 2 installers together.

Comment: Yeah; basically the best you can do is build a .exe installer (ours is in NSIS) that conditionally installs either both or just 32 bit depending on the platform

Comment: I wouldn't use NSIS or any other write your own because WiX Burn natively understands MSI and handles a lot of issues for you automatically.   Install, Uninstall, Upgrading, Caching and so on.

Comment: haven't used WiX burn; I should probably check it out one of these days

Comment: So you propose that I create 2 msi files, one using the 32-bit dll and one using the 64-bit dll and then use Burn and create one single installer, right? What I don't understand is how this installer is going to work, I mean will the common installer install both 32-bit and 64-bit when I am on a 64-bit system, which is the desirable installer's function?

Comment: yes.  The WiX Burn bootstrapper will present the UI experience to the user and the Add/Remove programs entry.  The 2 MSI's will install silently and not have an entry in add/remove programs.  Depending on how you configure it,  the 32bit MSI may or may not install on a 64bit machine and the 64bit msi will.  It depends on how you need to deploy your solution.  Sometimes a DLL is mutually exclusive (like a 32/64 driver)  and sometimes they both get installed ( like C++ runtimes )

Comment: Ok I will try to add the 2 msi in one installer and see if it works.

Comment: You should post a new question instead of asking additional questions in the comments section of a question that you haven't accepted the answer to.

Answer (score 0):

what I will do in such scenario is to focus mostly on 64 bit installer rather than creating different installer and bootstrapping it.
Below is my approach for the same, Please point me out if i am taking it wrong.

As Koka wants installer which will setup things for browser plugin and to make browser use according to platform. In such case consider
1> OS is 32 bit so there is no chance of 64 bit broswer, so keep installer simple with things setting up for 32 bit broswer.
2> Now os is 64 bit. chances are 32/64 bit browser, so create installer with different components for 32 bit and 64 bit, 32 bit component will setup things for 32 bit broswer and same with 64 bit component.And leave rest of the things to OS as 32 bit browser will always use 32 bit firebreath plugin.

I believe **Regsvr** will install plugin for all available browsers but it is considered [bad practice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb204770%28VS.85%29.aspx#no_selfreg) in an installer.
this is not a full proof as there are many things while installing browser plugin that need to be taken care by developer while creating installer.

Comment: Is there any example that I could look through in order to have a guide how to implement your proposal?

Comment: can you share some code which will add browser plugin? Create 64 bit installer as you have created previously and add extra another component which will do the same work but for 32 bit browsers. What i mean is consider I need to install driver on 64 bit system.While using driver windows by default search in SYSWOW64 or SYSTEM32 according to application bitness. so while installing i will install 32 bit and 64 bit driver at a time.(This requires only in 64 bit).SO if you adds 32 bit browser file and 64 bit browser files in 64 bit installer, Browser will automatically take according bitness.

Comment: even simply creating 64 bit installer with 64 bit browser plugin binaries may not work sometime as browser may be of 32 bit on 64 bit os.http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44191/Drivers-Installation-With-WiX has some similar example.